# Autocomplete removes border

Tags: javascript, html, css

My form has autocomplete off but all modern browsers ignore this. When a user types their name the border remains but when the user uses autocomplete the border is removed.

[image: Example of completed entry.]

```css
.half {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

input[type=name] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contain {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  resize: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="half">
  <form method="post" name="submitted" action="submitted" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="name" id="forename" name="forename" placeholder="Forename"><br>
    <div class="contain">
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Contact Me" required="">
  </form>
</div>
```

How would I go about maintaining the border even when autocompleted given autocomplete can't be entirely disabled.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem, because my browsers are not using autocomplete. Also, there is no `[type=name]`, so what is happening here is you're looking at the browser's error handling routines, which may change without notice. Don't rely on error handling always being the same.

Comment: That's not what's happening. The border I've added is removed when the form is filled with autocomplete. It should remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no way (really) to affect any `background` statements of Chrome `:-webkit-autofill`. We can manipulate anything, but not the `background`. The only solution i see is to cover the `input` in a parent with your border stylized border. And then protect white background color with `:-webkit-autofill` rules trick.

Although I replaced `.contain` with a `.gradien` class. And changed `type=name` to `type=text` (there is no such type ad `name`).

Now, even if you will switch `autocomplete="on"` - the styles will be totally the same as with no autocomplete. To keep gradient you have to cover all you `input` and `textarea` in parent element with `.gradient` class.

```css
.half {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top right, #006699, #9900CC);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  border: solid 5px transparent;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Change Autocomplete styles in Chrome*/

input[type=text]:-webkit-autofill,
input[type=text]:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input[type=text]:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  /* this will protect agains the blue highlite */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #fff inset;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  resize: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="half">
  <form method="post" name="submitted" action="submitted" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="gradient"><input type="text" id="forename" name="forename" placeholder="Forename"></div>
    <div class="gradient">
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Contact Me" required="">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Just noting that `-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #fff inset;` breaks any elements with `hover:`

Comment: I didn't understand. How is that?

Comment: Oh, I see, it's your next question. Will try to solve it

Comment: I have no idea. I've had to make the sacrifice of keeping the highlight. I assume it'd have to be applied elsewhere. The issue in my most recent question is to do with the border on hover. I only noticed so came back here to update this post also.